# Given $3x^2+x=1$, find $6x^3-x^2-3x+2010$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

> Given $3x^2+x=1$, find $6x^3-x^2-3x+2010$.

I substituted $3x^2 = 1-x$ in $6x^3-x^2-3x+2010$ and it simplified to
$$\frac{-8x}{3}+2010$$

I know this is a simple problem but I can't solve it. I think there's some method I'm not trying. Please help me with this.

Comment: Why not just solve for $x$ using the quadratic formula and then plug in?

Comment: @JackPfaffinger I tried that and it didn't work I got a wrong answer. And also it's not very elegant.

Comment: You made a mistake when substituting and simplifying. I got a result that does not depend on the choice of root of $3x^2+x=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$6x^3=2x-2x^2$$ so $$6x^3-x^2-3x+2010=-x-3x^2+2010 =2009$$

Comment: Someone thinks his/her answer is better than this one.

Answer (score 0):

$6x^3 = 2x-2x^2$
so 
$6x^3-x^2 -3x+2010 = 2x-2x^2-x^2-3x+2010$

And finally $-x-3x^2+2010 = -x-(1-x)+2010=2009$

Answer (score 0):

Just synthetic divide and subtract and add till you reduce to something manageable.

$6x^3 -x^2 -3x + 2010 = $

$6x^3+ 2x^2 - 3x^2 - 3x + 2010=$

$2x(3x^3 + x^2) - 3x^2 - 3x+2010=$

$2x - 3x^2 - 3x + 2010=$

$-3x^2 - x + 2010=$

$-(3x^2 + x) +x - x +2010=$

$-1 + 0 + 2010=$

$2009$.

Answer (score 0):

by using the long division
$$\frac{6x^3-x^2-3x+2010}{1}=\frac{6x^3-x^2-3x+2010}{3x^2+x}=(3x^2+x)(2x-1)-\frac{2x-2010}{3x^2+x}$$
$$=(1)(2x-1)-\frac{2x-2010}{1}=2009$$